# How to clear old mail in Linux?

Tags: mail-command

I want to clear the Linux mail for my account every day at 10pm. How can I accomplish it?

Comment: What part of the mail `man` page makes you think you can schedule things with `mail`?

Comment: @Anthon I suspect if s/he knew that they wouldn't be asking

Answer (score 2):

You could `crontab -e` to edit your personal list of cron jobs, and add the line:

```
0 22 * * * : > /var/mail/"$(whoami)"
```

which will, at 22:00 (10pm) every day, overwrite the file `/var/mail/<your username>` with empty data. If your mail file is stored somewhere else, you would need to change the path.

Comment: It's better to use `: > /var/mail/"$(whoami)"` as not all shells support empty redirection.